# Imported obj distort when selection to cursor

Tags: origin, obj, distort

I am currently working on terrain modeling, and i am importing a rhino file as obj to blender. I do the importing, set origin to geometry and then when trying to selection to cursor, the contour lines become distorted and twisted. Why is this happening?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you import multiple objects as curves. Each of them has a separate origin point and Snap Selection to Cursor snaps each object's origin point to the 3D Cursor individually. If you want to keep object locations relative to each other, you should chose Selection to Cursor(Keep Offset):

[image]

This will use your Transform Pivot Point setting to snap the group of object to the 3D Cursor and will keep the location of each object relative to other selected objects.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked!

Comment: If an answer is useful on Blender Stack Exchange, consider up-voting or accepting it as the answer.